# When I run npm run develop on server, I am unable to access it on the server IP, why?

Tags: node.js, strapi

I am trying to run `Strapi` project on `AWS Lightsail server`. When I run the command `npm run develop`, i can not access the admin dashboard. However, it works fine on my local computer. Am I missing something?

Comment: Per default, the server only binds to `localhost` thus, is only accessible from within the same machine. You can [update your config](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/admin-panel/customization.html#change-access-url) to make it accessible from elsewhere

Comment: @derpirscher I think the server will of course bind to the `localhost:port` only. Am I supposed to bind it to some public IP address? If I bind it on `localhost`, it should be accesible outside via the server's public IP address, right?

Comment: No, if you bind to localhost it's accessible from localhost only. Use the public ip

Comment: @derpirscher Thanks it worked, but I don't know why, for some reason, it didn't work on `AWS Lightsail`, so I had to switch to `Linode`, and now it works fine. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your config/server.js file, change the host ip directly or through environment variables like :

```
module.exports = 
({ env }) = > ({
    port: env.int('MYPORT','Your default value if your port not 
    accessible'),
    host: env('MYHOSTIP','default value'),
});
```

Now in your .env create your variables:

```
MYPORT=8080
MYHOSTIP=192.168.172.112
```

Comment: The address should be 127.0.0.1 right? And I should be able to access it anywhere outside via the server's public IP address. I thought that's how it works? Or is it something else?

Comment: No, actually the address here should be the public one of the server and not the localhost (127.0.0.1)  since the url you'll be accessing is `http://${host}:${port}` .

Comment: Thanks! That worked, but on `Linode`, I don't know why, for some reason it didn't work on `AWS LightSail`